# Switching Camera from front to Back or vice versa. What is the best approach?

Tags: android, android-camera

What is the best approach for switching between front & back camera & what factors do we have to take into account when we perform the switch.

Some posts suggest to restart the activity by changing the cameraId ? Is this approach efficient or is there any other better approach ?